# How to set up Tileserver-PHP for OSM data with custom style

Tags: php, tile-server, web-gis

I downloaded the files from https://github.com/maptiler/tileserver-php
and took them to my Ubuntu server (22.04 LTS) with Apache webserver into "tileserver" folder.

After this i downloaded OSM data as an mbtiles file (for a whole country) from here: https://data.maptiler.com/downloads/tileset/osm/

I took the mbtiles to the tileserver folder, so it now contains the following files:

1. .htaccess
2. README.md
3. tileserver.php
4. osm.mbtiles

If i call myserver/tileserver/tileserver.php i get a preview from the osm. mbtiles like this:
[image]

I found a great tool (https://maputnik.github.io/editor/#0.8/0/0) to make json files which can style the osm.mbtiles file on the server.

**How can i overwrite the default style (see the attached image) to this new stlye? I tried to rename it to "osm.json", but nothing happened, the preview was the same as before (default).**